# Get exit code from multiple bash scripts running in parallel

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code

I am running a 4 bash scripts in parallel, all 4 scripts are running at the same time:

`./script1.sh & ./script2.sh & ./script3.sh & ./script4.sh`

I would like to exit once either of them fail. I was trying to use something like an exit code , but it doesn't seem to run for parallel scripts. Is there a workaround?
Any bash/python solution would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will do it for you.
I borrowed (and modified) `non_blocking_wait` function from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/background-process-get-exit-code).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run your scripts here... Following sleep commands as an example
sleep 5 &
sleep 3 &
sleep 3 &

# Here, we get the pid of each running process an put in the array "pids"
pids=( $(jobs -p | tr '\n' ' ') )

echo "pids = ${pids[@]}"

non_blocking_wait()
{
    PID=$1
    if [ ! -d "/proc/$PID" ]; then
        wait $PID
        CODE=$?
    else
        CODE=127
    fi

    echo $CODE
}

while true; do

    # Check if all processes are still running
    n_running=$(jobs -l | grep -c "Running")

    if [ "${n_running}" -ne "3" ]; then
        # At least one processes finished/returned here,
        # check if exited in error
        for pid in ${pids[@]}; do
            ret=$(non_blocking_wait ${pid})
            echo "non_blocking_wait ${pid} ret = ${ret}"
            if [ "${ret}" -ne "0" ] && [ "${ret}" -ne "127" ]; then
                echo "Process ${pid} exited with error ${ret}"
                # Here we can take any desirable action such as
                # killing all children and exiting the program:
                kill $(jobs -p) > /dev/null 2>&1
                exit 1
            fi
        done

        if [ "${n_running}" -eq "0" ]; then
            echo "All processes finished successfully"
            exit 0
        fi
    fi

    sleep 1
done
```

If you simply run it, it will exit 0 when all processes ends:

```
$ ./script.sh 
pids = 17913 17914 17915
non_blocking_wait 17913 ret = 127 
non_blocking_wait 17914 ret = 0 
non_blocking_wait 17915 ret = 0 
non_blocking_wait 17913 ret = 127 
non_blocking_wait 17914 ret = 0 
non_blocking_wait 17915 ret = 0 
non_blocking_wait 17913 ret = 0 
All processes finished successfully
```

You can remove the parameter from one of the sleep commands to make it fail and see the program returning immediately:

```
$ ./script.sh 
sleep: missing operand
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
pids = 18005 18006 18007
non_blocking_wait 18005 ret = 127 
non_blocking_wait 18006 ret = 1 
Process 18006 exited with error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

```
parallel --line-buffer --halt now,fail=1 ::: ./script?.sh
echo $?
42
```

**Actual answer**

When running jobs in parallel, I find it useful to consider **GNU Parallel** because it makes so many aspects easy for you:

- resource allocation
- load spreading across multiple CPUs and across networks
- logging and output tagging
- error-handling - this aspect is of particular interest here
- scheduling, restarting
- input & output file name derivation and renaming
- progress reporting

So, I have made 4 dummy jobs `script1.sh` through `script4.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "script1.sh starting..."
sleep 5
echo "script1.sh complete"
```

Except `script3.sh` which fails before the others:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "script3.sh starting..."
sleep 2
echo "script3.sh dying"
exit 42
```

---

So, here's the default way to run 4 jobs in parallel, with the outputs of each all gathered and presented one after the other:

```
parallel ::: ./script*.sh
script3.sh starting...
script3.sh dying
script1.sh starting...
script1.sh complete
script4.sh starting...
script4.sh complete
script2.sh starting...
script2.sh complete
```

You can see `script3.sh` dies first and all its output is gathered and shown first, followed by the grouped output of the others. In simple terms, output is grouped by job and presented as each job finishes.

---

Now let's do it again, but only buffer the output by line rather than waiting for the jobs to finish and gather it on a per-job basis:

```
parallel --line-buffer ::: ./script*.sh 
script1.sh starting...
script2.sh starting...
script3.sh starting...
script4.sh starting...
script3.sh dying
script1.sh complete
script2.sh complete
script4.sh complete
```

We can clearly see that `script3.sh` dies and exits before the others, but they still run to completion. In simple terms, output is presented line-by-line in the order it occurs.

---

Now we want **GNU Parallel** to kill any running jobs the moment any single one dies:

```
parallel --line-buffer --halt now,fail=1 ::: ./script?.sh
script2.sh starting...
script1.sh starting...
script3.sh starting...
script4.sh starting...
script3.sh dying
parallel: This job failed:
./script3.sh
```

You can see that `script3.sh` died and none of the other jobs completed because **GNU Parallel** killed them.

You can also get the failing exit status:

```
echo $?
42
```

It is *far more flexible* than I have shown. You can change `now` to `soon` and instead of killing other jobs, it will just not start any new ones. You can change `fail=1` to `success=50%` so it will stop when half the jobs exit successfully, and so on.

You can also add `--eta` or `--bar` for progress reports and distribute jobs across your network and so on. Well worth reading up, in these days where CPUs are getting fatter (more cores) rather than taller (more GHz) - there is an excellent PDF available [here](https://zenodo.org/record/1146014/files/GNU_Parallel_2018.pdf?download=1).

**Note**: By default, **GNU Parallel** will keep as many jobs running in parallel as you have CPU cores. So, if you have fewer than 4 cores, you should probably add `-j 4` to my suggested answer to tell it to run up to 4 jobs in parallel even if only 1 or 2 cores are present.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use subprocess:

```py
import subprocess
import time


def do_that(scripts):
    ps = [subprocess.Popen('./'+s, shell=True) for s in scripts]
    while True:
        done = True
        for p in ps:
            rc = p.poll()
            if rc is None:  # Script is still running
                done = False
            elif rc:
                # if rc==0, script success to finish
                # otherwise it failed
                print('This script run failed:', p.args)
                running = set(ps) - {p}
                for i in running:
                    i.terminate()
                    print('Force terminate', i.args)
                return 1
        if done:
            print('All done.')
            return 0


def timeit(func):
    def runner(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print(func.__name__, 'cost:', round(end-start,1))
        return res
    return runner


@timeit
def main():
    scripts = ('script1.sh', 'script2.sh')
    do_that(scripts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`wait -n` waits for the next program to exit and returns its exit status.

```
pids=( )
./script1.sh & pids+=( $! )
./script2.sh & pids+=( $! )
./script3.sh & pids+=( $! )
./script4.sh & pids+=( $! )
for _ in "${pids[@]}"; do
  wait -n || { rc=$?; kill "${pids[@]}"; exit "$rc"; }
done
```